# Decode JWT tokens in .Net 4.0 based Application

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I'm working on a project which is based on .Net 4.0 Framework and implementing ASP.NET Web APIs. My requirement is to decode JWT tokens coming to API. I was exploring "using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JWT" but seems this is compatible with .Net 4.5 only. How do I access to JWT functions in my project which is based on .Net framework 4.0?

Comment: What have you already tried? StackOverflow is not a website for people to code something for you, please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your question, as it is know I flagged it as "too broad". That being said, I found this after a quick google search https://jwt.io with multiple .NET libraries (even one supported by Microsoft)

Comment: Do you have update about this?

Comment: This is quite a reasonable question. I'm also trying to find a lib support by .NET 4 (not 4.5)

Comment: @MindSwipe The question makes perfect sense. Don't think you have faced this problem yourself. Your comment is the one that is unhelpful.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a .net 4 project, found JWT-Dotnet helpful. Here are the [docs](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt#JwtNet).
Can be installed easily using nuget. Details on NUGET can be found [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JWT)

`Install-Package JWT -Version 7.3.1`

It supports .net from 3.5 onward. Decoding token is pretty easy. Below is a sample from documentation.

```
const string token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjbGFpbTEiOjAsImNsYWltMiI6ImNsYWltMi12YWx1ZSJ9.8pwBI_HtXqI3UgQHQ_rDRnSQRxFL1SR8fbQoS-5kM5s";
const string secret = "GQDstcKsx0NHjPOuXOYg5MbeJ1XT0uFiwDVvVBrk";

try
{
    IJsonSerializer serializer = new JsonNetSerializer();
    var provider = new UtcDateTimeProvider();
    IJwtValidator validator = new JwtValidator(serializer, provider);
    IBase64UrlEncoder urlEncoder = new JwtBase64UrlEncoder();
    IJwtAlgorithm algorithm = new HMACSHA256Algorithm(); // symmetric
    IJwtDecoder decoder = new JwtDecoder(serializer, validator, urlEncoder, algorithm);
    
    var json = decoder.Decode(token, secret, verify: true);
    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
catch (TokenExpiredException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token has expired");
}
catch (SignatureVerificationException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Token has invalid signature");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error I've found jose-jwt to support .NET4

Comment: Unfortunatly while I did find it supported .NET 4 i went down another route so have no code to show.